Bulletproof automotive drycontact input switch with constant current opto driver
Please comment on this circuit. I want to make sure a push button input SW? is as robust as possible before it goes into my processor after the U12A buffer.


Are you debouncing in software?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No shielded cable?  You have a lot of short circuit/over-current protection on a part of the circuit that is designed to be shorted to ground.

I don't think the buffer, current limiter, or polyfuse are necessary.
Some ideas for additional protection:
Add a 1nf ceramic cap at the connector to shunt high frequency noise.
Add a series resistor and diode clamp the input to GND.
You can add a second cap after the series resistor to add a bit of low pass filter. Cheap and won't hurt.
You could separate the grounds by using an isolated 5V supply.
